# EJB - GWT. Notificate GWT(javaScript) client about some events happened

Tags: java, gwt, ejb

I want to make document printing service using GWT(javascript+servlet) and EJB. What is the best way to cause EJB to notificate GWT client about some event is happened?

Of course, I can make it with using Timer (send request to EJB with some interval), but may be exist some more elegant way? (for example with callback, but I dont understand how to release it).

P.S.: I will use multitier architectur: JavaScript(GWT)+Servlet(GWT RPC)+EJB. And i working on document printing service (i want to notificate client that some file(s) is printed (also will be good if you give me advice of making progress bar)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options:

-Polling (e.g. using timer to send requests to the server)

-WebSockets (server can directly notify the client about changes, but sockets aren't supported in IE family yet)

-Some framework,  which just magically does stuff for you (for example [gwt-comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/))

Personally I would use polling, because may be it is slow and doesn't use server resources effectively, but it is the most stable one.

Comment: thanks for answer, but some people advised me to use callbacks if it possible... If you understand this idea, can you explain more depth about it?

Comment: @Hello I don't really sure what some people meant by *use callbacks if it possible*. You will be using a lot of callbacks, if you going to communicate with server from GWT app. So i think you have to ask those people again, cause what they said for GWT means the same as "use variables as much as possible"